# Ion-img Responsive Size

Tags: ionic3, responsive

I am using Ionic 3. I have an ion-img in my html and I set the dimensions because the size was not displaying correctly.

```
<ion-img width="362" height="688" src="../assets/imgs/artsUmbrellaSimoneKingman.png" style="background-color: transparent;"></ion-img>
```

My question is how do I make that image responsive? So that it is small when the screen is small.

None of the scss that I have used on the ion-img element seems to do anything.

I've looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523299/how-can-i-make-ion-img-responsive) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868969/img-responsive-doesnt-center)